# How can I access data elements in JSON when my keys are numeric (1,2,3....)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

My code so far:

/apis/get_json.php returns:

```
{"1":"value1","2":"value2","3":"value3"}
```

as an array to json in PHP (json_encode).

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("/apis/get_json.php",function(json_response,status){
         var json_response=JSON.parse(json_response)
          alert("Data: " + json_response.[1] + "\nStatus: " + status);
});
});
</script>
```

I get the error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Not sure what the syntax is if the key is numeric

Comment: This is a good question in some ways: your code is decent, your testcase is minimal and complete, your inputs are clear and your error is clear. Unfortunately, it's not clear to me why you did not simply look up this language feature in a JavaScript reference, which would have revealed the problem to you exceedingly quickly.

Comment: I was not clear on why numbers required [] when variables are accessed with .varname so maybe I need to further review the differences between data types. This was helpful none the less.

Comment: It's just a matter of what qualifies as a valid property identifier. An identifier must begin with a letter, `$` or `_`, followed by any of those or a number. A number can't be first, probably to avoid an ambiguity that the parser must then deal with since `.9` would look like either a valid decimal number or a valid property. Using square brackets, any value can be used, though its *toString* evaluation is what is ultimately used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue : To access the objects properties you can either use `obj.prop` or `obj[prop]`.In your case you used both (`.[]`) which is syntax error so,

Convert,

`alert("Data: " + json_response.[1] + "\nStatus: " + status);` to

```
alert("Data: " + json_response['1'] + "\nStatus: " + status); // [`1`] just to avoid of implicit converstion
```

Read More about [Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators)

Comment: I'd rather use `json_response['1']` without implicit conversion and to avoid confusion with a vanilla array. `Object.keys(json_response)` returns key names as strings, after all

Comment: @o.v.: There's no distinction between the indices of a vanilla array and the properties of any other object. They're all treated as strings.

Comment: *"just to avoid headache of implicit converstion"* What headache?

Comment: @cookiemonster I am talking about javascript engine `coercion` in case of [1]

Comment: @Pilot: I know. Why do you think that's a headache? I'm not understanding the problem you're alluding to.

Comment: @cookiemonster removed ***headache*** from ans

Comment: Oh. That word really wasn't the point. There's no reason to attempt to avoid any implicit conversion that wouldn't be equally applicable to using the same property accessor syntax on Arrays.

Comment: Not really. In Firefox they're nearly identical. Not sure why you used `alert()` in the jsPerf though. Either way, are you suggesting that people use strings when accessing Array members too?

Comment: @cookiemonster please do not blame me..That benchmark result I found somewhere on google..I nver recommend using `alert()`

Comment: Here's an updated test that includes an Array too. http://jsperf.com/propaccessor/2 It shows equal performance in Firefox, and much faster performance in Chrome when using `[1]` instead of `["1"]`. Either way, doesn't matter. In Chrome, the speeds were nearly 1 billion operations per second. If/when there happens to be a performance difference on different browsers, it's not a compelling reason to alter coding style, since the difference is imperceptible and can change with the next release.